# Advice required on iron router and meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, iron-router

How would I get the links on the left (sidebar) to open up separate pages on the right side of the screen?

I've been going through some of the tutorials that are being served by google searches. I try to put the {{> yield}} in the body but it doing that, messes up everything. My understanding is that yield must be placed where ever the routed page must appear. Please let me know how to go about with this.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
<body>
    <div id= 'wrapper'> 
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            {{> SideBar}}
        </div>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        {{> PageContent}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


<template name ='SideBar'>
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">Start Bootstrap  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                 <a href="{{ pathFor 'Dashboard' }}">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ pathFor 'Overview' }}">Overview</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
 </template>   

<template name ='PageContent'>
                   <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                         **{{> yield}}**
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</template>
```

Clicking on Dashboard/Overview should render the below template on the right of the screen

```
<template name ='Dashboard'>
       <h1> testing dashboard</h1>
</template>

<template name ='Overview'>
   <h1> testing Overview</h1>
</template>
```

**This is my routes.js**

```
Router.route('/Dashboard', function(){this.render('Dashboard');
                                     });
Router.route('/Overview', function(){this.render('Overview');
                                    });


Router.route('/profiles/manuel', function () {
this.layout('profileLayout');
this.render('profileDetail');
});
```

**Config.js:**

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'PageContent'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Remove the body tag.

2.Include the content of your body tag inside your profile layout template.
This worked for me.

Comment: You mean.. do this?

        <template name ='profileLayout'>
            <div id= 'wrapper'> 
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                {{> SideBar}}
            </div>
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            {{> PageContent}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

Comment: I reworked on the whole page container. Basically removed each template and then created one big template encompassing the side bar as well as the right display container. I also set the default template in iron router to point to the sidebar so that it's displayed static on all pages. It works, for now. Until I break it again.